# Help the lighting doesnt work and some part of the object is black

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, lighting, error

[image]So i try to learn to create the chair just like blender guru tutorial, and when i try to render the model to finish the lighting lesson, it turn out like this (as shown in the picture), like the lighting doesnt work on some part of the object. Does anybody know how to fix this? thanks a lot

Comment: if your world is black and if your material is super reflective, it will only show black, is it the problem here?

Comment: Actually the world isnt black, and the material is using image texture with normal map for bump, so I guess it isnt super reflective either. I dont know if i mess up on the material or not

Comment: please share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/ecebe94ae2f44467a863ddf4312ca92e here is the file for the chair, thanks again mate

Comment: please pack the images and share again  ;)  it may have to do with your normal image? Try to switch your Image Texture to Non-Color and lower down the Strength of the Normal Map?

Comment: omg yeah you are right i got the image file wrong, i should have use the normal instead of the reflective image texture, and now its all good. thanks a lot mate!

Comment: @Misterp21 consider adding your own answer to this question with the solution, I think the image you've included is good and someone with the same problem would instantly recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Check your normal image, switch the *Image Texture* node to *Non-Color*, maybe lower down the *Strength* of the *Normal Map* node.

Answer (score 0):

so the answer to this thing is because of the image texture file is wrong, it should be using the normal one instead of the reflective one, the pitch black color was shown because of the material is too reflective to absorb light in blender. Thanks everyone for the help to solve this